# group by specific values in different fields SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like this (sorry but don't know how to put things in a table format):

```
  |  ID| Status        | Business Area |Business sub area| ...|
1 | ongoing| Area 1        | Null            | ...|
2 | closed | Area 2        | Sub-area a      | ...|
...
```

I need to count all the cases with a different criteria for each column (a count based on the status) but grouped by specific values in either the business area or the business sub area.

The table I want would have the following structure

```
Groups    | total | count of ongoing | count of closed |
Area 1    | 10    | 5                | 5               |
Sub-area A| 6     | 3                | 3               |
```

My issue isn't really to do with getting the columns as I can work that out, but I don't know if it's possible to group the records in the way i've done above.

For my table there will be values in the business area field that I don't want records to group under and likewise for the sub area group which is why i want a way for the groups to be specific values rather than entire fields.

How would I group by specific values that exist in different fields in SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `COALESCE()`:

```
select coalesce(business_sub_area, business_area) as groups,
       . . .
. . .
group by coalesce(business_sub_area, business_area);
```

Comment: Is there a reason we need to select it separately as groups rather than just use the coalesce function in the group by clause? For argument's sake can my query just be: select count(case number) from table group by coalesce(business sub area, business area)

Comment: @SaleemKhan . . . The two are different. If you use `group by business_sub_area, business_area)`, you will get a separate row for each sub area that is in different business areas.  That may be what you actually want to do.

Comment: Makes sense. One more thing: there is a small number of records that have a business sub area and a random business area that would also need to be a group for other records (presumably because something went wrong in the data entry procedure). Would the coalesce avoid a duplicate count if i just wanted the badly entered records to be counted under their respective sub areas?